# Is the html sending null or empty?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have some cases here.

A pair of radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="One" name="MyRadio" value="">
<input type="radio" id="Two" name="MyRadio">
```

So I have 3 scenarios.

- I select "One"
- I select "Two"
- I select none and I send the form.

And a similar case with select

```
<option value=''>Three</option>
<option>Four</option>
```

My questions are

a) What will be send in cases 1,2 and 3 (and 4, 5 and 6)?

b) In case I need to check the values, should I use isset() or empty() when reciving them in the next script?

Answer (score 1):

With the first radio, this would be an empty string. With the second radio, this wouldn't be in the POST data. You can test both with `empty()`.

To confuse matters, the option without a value would have the text send to the server so 'Four' where as an empty string would be sent for Three.

However, this is from memory. What you can do is paste `$_POST` into `var_dump()` to check the results yourself :)

Comment: Thank you, I can't seem to find the keys for inline code when answering with iPhone.